# AndEngine collision detection

Tags: andengine

I want to detect sprite collision on a hill but my sprite detect collision before hill as it detects rectangular shape. I want to detect collision on hill edges, I draw a triangle by using mesh but collideswith() method not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1) You can use the [Box2D extension](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension) and let Box2D handle the colisons

2) You can use the [AndEngineCollisionExtension](https://github.com/MakersF/AndEngineCollisionsExtension)
-You'll have to replace your `Sprite` with `PixelPerfectSprite`

Comment: Thanks... I used pixelPerfectSprite and it worked, but i have a problem. My collision detection have some problem. I wrote pixelperfectMask to sdcard by using  AndroidMaskUtils.writeMaskToSDCardAsImage but image is inverted. What is wrong with me

Comment: @Anilkumar I haven't actually used the extension, so I can't help you there. Sorry